# laravel trailing Slashes redirect to localhost

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, trailing-slash

When I try this

```
http://localhost/Testlaravel/public/users/login
```

it works. But when I try

```
http://localhost/Testlaravel/public/users/login/
```

it redirects me to

```
http://localhost/users/login/
```

Any idea why?

This my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Testlaravel/public/

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: i try it but now it's redirect to http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/Testlaravel/public/users/login

Comment: ok i added RewriteBase /Testlaravel/public/ and now it work thx :)

Comment: For me, the line: **RewriteBase /Testlaravel/** worked, as i am not using public folder and got rid of it. Thanks.

Comment: It's not work for me. `http://localhost/newproject/public/login/` works fine. But `http://localhost/newproject/public/login/` will redirect to `http://localhost/login`

Comment: @kupendra: Each one's problem is different, this is not answer to your problem. Post a new question and we'll look into that.

Comment: @anubhava i have same problem

Comment: It redirects just where it should for me, but now I get 500 error page.

Answer (score 1):

> If the above method not working then clear your browser history with
>   cache and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I Just added this to my .htaccess file and it worked fine!

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^
```

Answer (score 0):

My project directory is

c:\wamp\www\laravel_apps\li3\

and changed the .htaccess inside public folder to the following

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /laravel_apps/li3/public/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

i just replaced

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /laravel_apps/li3/public/$1 [L,R=301]
```

now, if you put an slash at an end of the url it will redirected to the same page