# URL with trailing slashes gets redirected to localhost in laravel 5

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, redirect, laravel-5

The fix in the duplicate question doesn't work.

I tried all the Fixes in stackoverflow but nothing seems to be working
[laravel trailing Slashes redirect to localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735527/laravel-trailing-slashes-redirect-to-localhost)

Route

```
Route::get('/admin', array('as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'Admin\Admin@getLogin'));
```

This URL is working fine
http://localhost/app/admin

but when I add a trailing slash in front of it http://localhost/app/admin/
it gets redirected to http://localhost/admin

Help!

Comment: I have said that it is not working.read my question.

Comment: what your htaccess? could you please share with us?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Ju5jTetX

Comment: any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Added this and it worked!

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5suvnwyL/1/ check this for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153332/how-to-disable-the-all-days-before-the-the-day-from-input-value-on-bootstrap-dat

Answer (score 2):

i too had this problem and mine need a combination of the above with suggestions from some other posts. Don't remember from which posts
anyways this was my .htaccess that got me working correctly.
And 1 more thing our project did not have public in the url.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /PROJECT_NAME

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```