# Laravel 5 : URL with trailing slashes gets redirected to localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5

I can access my url with `http://localhost/rnd/public/coeg-admin` but if I visit `http://localhost/rnd/public/coeg-admin/` it gets redirected to `http://localhost/coeg-admin`.

I just follow [laravel trailing Slashes redirect to localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735527/laravel-trailing-slashes-redirect-to-localhost) and [URL with trailing slashes gets redirected to localhost in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775997/url-with-trailing-slashes-gets-redirected-to-localhost-in-laravel-5)

But it's doesn't work as expected, Here is my `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Set base URL
    # RewriteBase /rnd/public/
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here is my `apache2.conf`

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/rnd/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        #AllowOverride None
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

How, I can redirect url with slashes at the end to url without slashes at the end ?

Thanks, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I do was remove `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]` from the public/.htaccess

don't forget to clear cache too, because chrome redirecting-cache saved in browser too