# GET and POST requests routing to same controller in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

My problem: when I do `GET /print-jobs/`, it correctly routes to the `index` method in my controller. When I say `POST /print-jobs/`, it should route to my `store` method. However, it seems to be routing to my `index` method as well. This only happens in my production environment, where I am running Laravel under Apache.

Route code:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'print-jobs'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'PrintJobMasterController@index');
    Route::get('/{printJob}', 'PrintJobMasterController@show')->where(['printJob' => '[0-9]+']);
    Route::post('/', 'PrintJobMasterController@store');
    ...
 }
```

Relevant controller code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class PrintJobMasterController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Display all PrintJob models
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request) {
        Log::info('PJMC::index: rendering index of all print jobs');
        ...;
    }
    /**
     * Store a newly job request en masse
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request) {
        Log::info("PJMC::store: creating new job");
        ...;
    }
    ...;
}
```

Now, I expect to see in my logs a message starting with `PJMC::index:` when I call `GET /print-jobs/` and a message starting with `PJMC::store:` when I call `POST /print-jobs/`. However, both times when do this in the browser: `$.get('/print-jobs')` and `$.post('/print-jobs/', {_token: window.Laravel.csrfToken, ...})` from my browser, I see the following in my log file:

> ```
> [2017-06-09 10:27:17] local.INFO: PJMC::index: rendering index of all print jobs
> [2017-06-09 10:27:23] local.INFO: PJMC::index: rendering index of all print jobs
> ```

Both times the request routes to the `index` method! I looked in my network history on my browser and the requests are indeed registered as a `GET` and a `POST` respectively, which leads me to suspect that the problem is somewhere on the backend. However, when I call these routes using Laravel's test suite, I don't have any problems.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you seeing anything in the laravel error or php error logs?

Comment: try putting your post request on top of the routes!  Route::post  goes first!

Comment: @AdamA I am not seeing any errors. Those lines in the log is the only hint I'm getting.

Comment: @L.Kelmendi I tried that and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the trailing slash `/` in your `$.post()` and it should work.

**Wrong:**

```
$.post('/print-jobs/', {_token: window.Laravel.csrfToken, ...})
```

**Correct:**

```
$.post('/print-jobs', {_token: window.Laravel.csrfToken, ...})
```

Comment: I think that did it. Thanks! Why does this make a difference? Should I avoid trailing slashes in URIs in general? Are there cases when they are appropriate/necessary and when they are not?

Comment: When using Laravel yes. There's a redirect rule in the `.htaccess` file. Have a look at [Laravel trailing slashes redirect to localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735527/laravel-trailing-slashes-redirect-to-localhost)